# Prove that F is bijective. (one-to-one correspondence)

Tags: real-analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $A,B$ be sets. Let $P(A) = \{S: S ⊂ A\}$ denote the set of subsets of $A$ (The Power Set of A$).

Remember that $B^A$ is the set of all functions $f : A \to B$.

Consider a function $F : P(A) \to \{0, 1\}^A$ such that for every $S \in P(A)$, we have:
$F(S)(a) = 1$ if $a ∈ S$  and   $F(S)(a) = 0$ otherwise .

Prove that $F$ is bijective.

Hint:   The function $F(S)$ is known as the characteristic function of $S$. It is common to denote $F(S)$ as $\chi_S$.

Hey guys,
I am having a really hard time at math in university, I have never had that contact with this kind of math and my teacher doesn't actually give support because he is always assuming that I should know everything. I know that it's probably really simple for more experienced people, but to me it is not trivial.

I been studying and tried to solve this problem first by analyzing the cardinality of the sets, because I think that for a function be one-to-one correspondence, the domain and co-domain must have the same number of elements. So I did | P(A) | = 2^n in which n is the number of elements of set A. And | {0,1}^A | = 2^n in which 2 represents the number o elements of set {0,1} and n the number of elements of set A. Therefore, they do have the same cardinality.

Now, we have to prove that this function is either one-to-one and onto for it to be bijective. So let's first prove that it is one-to-one:

I tried to solve this by considering two subsets of A, let be S1 and S2. And let F(S1) = F(S2). Now, I have to somehow prove that S1 = S2,  but I get struct and don't really know how to do this.

Then, I have to prove that the function is onto. And to do that I think I have to confirm that every function that belongs to the co-domain set {0,1}^A has a "correspondent" in the domain set. But how?

Comment: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on formatting for this site.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.

Comment: Hi @GWA! You should always include part of your own research when posting on this site. This is not meant as a website where other people do your homework.

Comment: I am sorry. I am really new to this kind of forum and also really new to math. I tried to improve my question.

Comment: Thanks for adding your attempt. You've significantly improved your question. At least we know that you know the definitions.

Comment: Hint for injectivity: Note that $F(S_1)$ and $F(S_2)$ are themselves functions. What does it mean for two functions to be equal? Well, it means that they agree on every input from the domain. So for every $a\in A$, we have $F(S_1)(a)=F(S_2)(a)$. Now can you conclude using the definition of $F(S)$?

Comment: Thank you Benjamin. I understand.

I am now thinking on taking a different approach to solve this problem based on the definition of a bijective function. A bijective function is invertible. 

I have already figured the cardinality of both domain and co-domain, equal. So if I prove that the function G(F) = F^-1(S) exists, then I will have solved the problem, maybe. But again, I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Judging by your comment above, it seems like you want an explicit inverse for the function:
$$F: \mathcal{P}(A) \to \{0,1\}^A \ , \ S \mapsto \chi_S$$

where $\chi_S$ is just shorthand for the way that you've chosen to define the function $F(S): A \to \{0,1\}$. Now, if you want an explicit inverse, then you need to, in some sense, address the surjectivity question (which you were unable to do in your original post). Here's how to do it.

Let $f: A \to \{0,1\}$ be a function. Define the following set:
$$K_f := \{x \in A: f(x) = 1\}$$

Then, I claim that $f = \chi_{K_f}$. This should be easy for you to show. This proves your surjectivity claim. But now, define the function:
$$G: \{0,1\}^{A} \to \mathcal{P}(A) \ , \ f \mapsto K_f$$
I'll leave it to you to show that this is actually a well-defined function and that this does actually work.